# How to retrieve full text tweets using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am trying to scrape tweets from a user-defined Twitter profile. Having read previous posts I understand that the Twitter JSON has a section for extended tweets. I've added `tweet_mode='extended'` into my `api.user_timeline` section and changed `.text` to `.full_text.`

However, I am still getting truncated tweets. I understand that retweets have a full_text attribute but I am scraping the timeline and not separating tweets from retweets.

Is there a way to universally query tweets and retrieve the full_text version. I have included my code below.

```
screen_name_list = ['@x']

for name in screen_name_list:
    user = api.get_user(name)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = name, count = 200,tweet_mode='extended', include_rts=True)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
      print 'getting tweets before %s' % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = name, count=200, max_id=oldest, tweet_mode='extended')

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')] for tweet in alltweets]
    tweet_time = [index[1] for index in outtweets]
    tweet_list = [index[2] for index in outtweets]
```

Comment: can you show how you're getting truncated tweets? with `tweet_mode='extended'`, checking through some of the tweets in `alltweets` all seem to have `'truncated': False`, and a tweet.`full_text` appears to have the full tweet content, not truncated. even the content of `outtweets[0][2]` matches the full text of `alltweets[0].full_text` more information or examples of the results you are getting would help.

Comment: I can get full text of tweets produced by a user. However, if the user retweets a tweet then the retweeted tweet is limited to 140 characters, i.e I'm not getting the full retweet.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace

```
tweet.full_text
```

with

```
tweet.retweeted_status.full_text if tweet.full_text.startswith("RT @") else tweet.full_text
```

you will get the full text of the retweet, albeit without the "RT" at the front, so you may also want to add another column in your CSV to indicate retweets, e.g.:

```
[1 if tweet.full_text.startswith("RT @") else 0] for tweet in alltweets
```